# Change legend position gnuplot

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I want to change the legend position from the top right of the graph to make it next to each line in the graph

i used

```
 plot[0:100000][] 'ccatt.txt' with line title "CCA", 'easctt.txt' with line title "ESAC",'hqtt.txt' with line title "Holy Qur'an"
```

any advice ?

Comment: What do you mean with "next to each line"??

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it automatically. As workaround you can use the `labels` plotting style, and put the title at the first point of the line with a certain offset:

```
plot 'ccatt.txt' with line notitle, \
     '' using 1:2:('CCA') every ::0::0 with labels left offset char 0,-1 notitle,
     'easctt.txt' with line notitle,\
     '' using 1:2:('ESAC') every ::0::0 with labels left offset char 0,-1 notitle
```

The `every ::0::0` selects the first point an places there the label `CCA`, left aligned with a vertical offset of minus one character height.